# asp.net handler.ashx running only on refresh in ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am trying to display image in asp.net page at runtime
so I have written an handler page. and using that page as url source
like image.imageurl = "~/handler.ashx" in  a button click event.

however when I put my imagebox and button inside ajax update panel.
code inside handler execute only on first click after page load but not on second click.
I need to refresh the page. how can I achieve image update without refresh on button click ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i resolve issue by making following changes to code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Handler.ashx?guid=" + Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

the key point is it need an new url every time.

more details on

[Using ASP.NET AJAX UpdatePanel with Handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236335/using-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-with-handlers)

Answer (score 0):

code
handler which return image which is obtain from wcf service

```
public class Handler : IHttpHandler
{
    imageService.HelloWorldServiceClient cli = new imageService.HelloWorldServiceClient();

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
{
    byte [] buffer = cli.getImage();
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    context.Response.Buffer = true;
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
    context.Response.Flush();
    context.Response.End();
}
```

I ma using below code on button click

```
 Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Handler.ashx";
```

both image control and button is in ajax update panel.